# Program for user to get to 25, unable to get cases to perform any action

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program that is a kind of game, seeing how many tries it takes a user to get to 25. Currently I am facing an issue where I am unable to get any of my cases to effect the main int labeled as user num.

```
package com.AndrewWebster.cx;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class WhileLoopDecisions {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    getTo25();
}
static void getTo25() {
    System.out.println("The goal is to get to 25 in as few tries as possible");
    int min = 1;
    int max = 5;
    int userNum = (int)(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min); 
    int guesses = 0;
    while (userNum !=25) {
        System.out.println("Your current number value is " + userNum + " Please enter a number 
to make a decision:");
        System.out.println("1. Divide " + userNum + " by 2"+"\n2. Multiply " + userNum + " by 
2" + "\n3. Add 4 to " + userNum + "\n4. Subtract 1 from " + userNum);
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int userChoice = keyboard.nextInt();
        switch (userChoice) {
        case '1' :
            userNum = userNum / 2; 
            break;
        case '2' :
            userNum = userNum * 3;
            break;
        case '3' :
            userNum = userNum + 4;
            break;
        case '4' :
            userNum = userNum +4;
            break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the switch statement you are treating the userChoice as a string, when you have  taken it out as an integer. So it was missing everything in the switch statement and leaving the variable userNum alone:

```
package com.AndrewWebster.cx;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class WhileLoopDecisions {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        getTo25();
    }

    static void getTo25() {
        System.out.println("The goal is to get to 25 in as few tries as possible");
        int min = 1;
        int max = 5;
        int userNum = (int)(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min); 
        int guesses = 0;
        while (userNum !=25) {
            System.out.println("Your current number value is " + userNum + " Please enter a number to make a decision:");
            System.out.println("1. Divide " + userNum + " by 2"+"\n2. Multiply " + userNum + " by 2" + "\n3. Add 4 to " + userNum + "\n4. Subtract 1 from " + userNum);
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            int userChoice = keyboard.nextInt();
            switch (userChoice) {
                case 1 :
                    userNum = userNum / 2; 
                    break;
                case 2 :
                    userNum = userNum * 3;
                    break;
                case 3 :
                    userNum = userNum + 4;
                    break;
                case 4 :
                    userNum = userNum +4;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```